# How to bind an object to a dom element in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Guys I have some simple html, for illustration purposes say it looks like this,

```
<div>{{class.name}}</div>
<div>
    <div>{{class.teacher.name}}</div>
    <div>{{class.teacher.age}}</div>
    <div>{{class.teacher.rating}}</div>
</div>
```

now the model as  you can see has a class object which has a name property and a teacher property.  What I would like to do is avoid the duplication in this code so that my bindings look more like this.

```
<div>{{class.name}}</div>
<div some-directive-here="class.teacher">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <div>{{age}}</div>
    <div>{{rating}}</div>
</div>
```

Does angular support a directive where I can create a new scope for a dom element as shown above? I don't want to use ng-controller as it create a new scope and disconnects me from the original model data.

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing available out of the box. A new scope doesn't disconnect you from the rest of the data though, unless you create a new *isolate* scope. Otherwise the new child scope inherits all properties from the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MqesLIUA1kq1S7BLal3N?p=preview

A simple directive which creates a new scope and extend it with the evaluated expression of it's parent scope.

#### Solution:

```
app.directive('newScope', function($parse){
  return {
    scope:true,
    compile: function (tElm,tAttrs){
      var fn = $parse(tAttrs.newScope);

      return function(scope, elm, attrs){
        var property = fn(scope.$parent);
        property = angular.isObject(property) ? property : {};
        angular.extend(scope, property);
      }      
    } 
  }
})
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Little surprised angular doesn't do this out of the box as it makes binding expressions far cleaner.  Thanks!

Comment: Angular supports custom directives out-of-the-box, you should not care if it's a core or a plugin.

Comment: you don't have to read parent scope because with {scope:true} you created new non-isolate scope  http://plnkr.co/edit/RTZdKxRShdsr6fxy2kCo?p=preview

Comment: @MatjazLipus It's bad to rely on scope inheritance in this case. See this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJJPDya2DJIE7CaUAPaA?p=preview , all child elements post linking functions could possibly shadow our object.

Comment: @llan one thing I did notice with your solution is that functions defined on the scope cannot be accessed with directives such as ng-click.  angular.extend only copies properties.

Comment: I updated the plunker, i double checked that it does copy the functions , and also inherit..

Comment: @Llan you are using properties for the functions.  I am using the objects proto type.  See plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/Mdvn3p6bHHry78qeTxi4?p=preview

Comment: This also doesn't work to simplify model binding.  So it only works for displaying read-only data. ng-model="name" does not work if you were to apply it to an input box under the new scope.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the solution is consider async solutions. I have taken the plnkr example and updated the compile function and set the class-property after 2 seconds.

http://plnkr.co/edit/X8y3ArvTD3WDZIIB3qFk?p=preview

```
app.directive('newScope', function($parse){
  return {
    scope:true,
    compile: function (tElm,tAttrs){
      var init = false;
      var attr = tAttrs.newScope;
      var fn = $parse(attr);

      var linkFunction = function (scope, elm, attrs) {

        if (!init) {
          scope.$watch(attr, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            linkFunction(scope, elm, attrs);
          });
        }

        var property = fn(scope.$parent);
        property = angular.isObject(property) ? property : {};
        angular.extend(scope, property);

        init = true;

      };

      return linkFunction;    
    } 
  }
})
```